# Need to download file from gridview

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm Newbie to Sharepoint.Please help me out.

1.I need to create a sp gridview in the sharepoint.

2.I need to write code where it will show the Sharepoint document library in sp grid view.

3.Now i want to Download the documents which are displaying in the sp gridview from the sharepointment library when clicked on the name.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hyperlink in your gridview and set the url to the document URl.
When user clicks on hyperlink the document will be downloaded.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If someone adds any new file to sharepoint library, will spgridview update accordingly?

Comment: How are you populating your gridview?

Comment: I have no idea.Can you please provide me a code snippet